# how to find the mysql query in ofbiz framework

Tags: mysql, sql, ofbiz

I'm new in ofbiz.Now I'm trying  to customize the module of ofbiz frame. Is it possible to find the database query in ofbiz?

Answer (score 1):

GenericDAO.java contains code (line 755 in the version I'm using) that logs the query if it's over a 150 millseconds. This can be modified to print the query and it's time regardless of the time it takes or to whatever limit you are interested in checking.